# Remove all http and https from HTML but exclude placeholder

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to remove all `http:` and `https:` in the HTML files but exclude `placeholder="http:` and `placeholder="https:`. I have tried the following example but every http: and https: will be removed:

```
/(?!placeholder=")(http:|https:)/
```

Comment: Use `/(?<!placeholder=")https?:/`

Comment: Has worked, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace the lookahead with a lookbehind. Besides, you may reduce the alternation to a mere `https?:` pattern, where `s?` means *1 or 0 `s`*:

```
'/(?<!placeholder=")https?:/'
    ^                   ^^
```

If you want to make sure the `placeholder`  is matched as a whole word, add a word boundary:

```
'/(?<!\bplaceholder=")https?:/'
      ^^
```

If there must be a whitespace before `placeholder`, replace `\b` with `\s`.

**Details**

- `(?<!\bplaceholder=")` - a location inside a string that is immediately preceded with a whole word `placeholder` and then `="`
- `http` - a `http` substring
- `s?` - an optional `s`
- `:` - a colon.